# scatterplot (X1,X2) grouped by factor: add a curve connecting the points corresponding to maxima of X1 in each group, with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Example plot:

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
p  <- ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=cyl))
p <- p + geom_point()
p
```

[image]

For each group (each number of cylinders), `mpg` has a maximum. I would like to plot a line which connects the points with maximum `mpg` in each group. I don't know how to do it: I thought I could create another dataframe, containing only the maxima of `mpg` in each group and the corresponding values of `disp`. I tried with `summarize` from `dplyr`, but I cannot retain the `disp` values corresponding to the maxima of `mpg`:

```
> foo <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(maxmpg=max(mpg))
> foo
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

     cyl maxmpg
  (fctr)  (dbl)
1      4   33.9
2      6   21.4
3      8   19.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- as.factor(df$cyl)
p  <- ggplot(data=df,aes(x=mpg,y=disp,color=cyl))
p <- p + geom_point()
p + geom_line(data=df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(mpg==max(mpg)), color="black")
```

Comment: cool! It works. I understand that  `df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(mpg==max(mpg))` supplies the `data` argument for `geom_line`. I don't understand about `aes(group=1)` though. It looks like  `p + geom_line(data = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(mpg==max(mpg)), color="black")` gives the same result as yours. Is there any specific reason to add `aes(group=1)`?

Comment: You're right, I kicked it out. (Thought I remembered geom_line complaining...)